# Buscar variações de palavra

Tags: c#, asp.net

tenho uma frase que preciso verificar se ela atende à uma regra porém pode haver variação na escrita (acentuação, espaços a mais ou a menos,...)

Exemplo:

```
string fraseProcurada = "Cadastro de Usuários - SP";

if (fraseRecebida.Contains(fraseProcurada)
   //recebi a frase que procurava
```

porém, nesse exemplo, pode ocorrer do usuário digitar:

- Cadastro de usuarios
- cadastro de usuario
- cadastro de usuario - são paulo
- cadastro de usuarios SP
- cadastro de usuario  -  S.P.

Uma certa quantidade de variações que na verdade atende o que eu procuro.
Bom pensei primeiro em fazer um array com essas possiveis formas mas não sei se existe algo mais certo e facil de fazer (tipo RegEx).

Alguma sugestão?

Obrigada.

Comment: Remover espaços duplos, colocar tudo em minusculo, remover acentuos e ai sim fazer a verificação, não funcionaria?

Comment: David, sim mas isso é o mais simples... o que eu perguntei é se tem uma forma bem mais pratica (no ex. RegEx) ao invés de criar um array de possibilidades.

Comment: Sem uma busca mecânica (usando um array de possibilidades para cada elemento), o caminho a percorrer é longo, você precisaria criar um mecanismo de pesquisa como o que o google tem. As variações são inúmeras: "cadastor de usuários", "cadstro de users", "são paulo - cad. usuário", "cadastro usuarios sampa" e por aí vai...

Comment: Acredito que determinar os limites das variações (considerando ou não possibilidades que podem ser expressas em RegEx, por exemplo) e buscar uma solução mais restrita.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algumas comparação não seriam possíveis, como usando "S.P" ou mesmo "São Paulo", pois não há como um código genérico o suficiente, como de `Contains` ou `IndexOf` identificar isso, saber por exemplo que "SP" significa o mesmo que "São Paulo".
Nesses casos, precisaria criar um dicionário que informasse as semelhanças para ajudar.
Para os casos em que a comparação se resume a acentos, maiúsculas e minúsculas, usar todas as variações de `CompareOptions` em conjunto com `IndexOf` já resolve muitos casos. Isso pode ser feito assim:

```
static bool Comparar(string texto, string textoAComparar)
{
    var index = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf
        (texto, textoAComparar, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | 
         CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols | CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace);
    return index != -1;
}
```

Isso irá atender a maioria dos casos. Aqui um exemplo do código funcionando: https://dotnetfiddle.net/S1Jscu

Comment: Ricardo, foi o que eu imaginava.. eu não ia ter como fugir de um array. Eu achava que poderia ter até uma forma com RegEx mas como pode ter uma variação muito grande de frases...o codigo iria ficar grande de qq forma.

obrigada :)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode normalizar a palavra tornando todos os caracteres em sua versão sem acento e em caixa baixa. Você pode utilizar o namespace System.Text para realizar a conversão de caracteres:

```
string s1 = new String(); 
string s2 = null;
s2 = s1.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Mas a pergunta é relacionada ao `C#`

Comment: Peço desculpas, não havia notado a tag. Vou editar.

Comment: pois é, C#... procurei e vi que também existe Normalize no C# porém não funcionou (nao ocorreu nada):

string t = fraseRecebida.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
t = t.replaceAll("\\p{M}", "").toLowerCase();

Comment: Se não me engano, FormD Só indica se a cadeia está normalizada, FormC indica e realiza a substituição dos caracteres se possível...

Comment: Marcos observei aqui que já é feito isso por parte do código, a questao fica em cima mesmo das variações possiveis. mas obrigada pela ajuda :)

Comment: Entendo, Boa sorte Andreia!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar uma classe helper para esses tratamentos adicionando esses métodos para o tipo string e ir adicionando os métodos para os tratamentos que deseja, removendo todos os caracteres que achar pertinente. Veja o exemplo:

```
public static class StringHelper
{

    public static string RemoverAcentos(this string texto)
    {
        StringBuilder retorno = new StringBuilder();
        var arrTexto =
            texto.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).ToCharArray();

        foreach (var letra in arrTexto)
        {
            if (System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(letra) !=
                System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
                retorno.Append(letra);
        }
        return retorno.ToString();
    }

    public static string RemoverEspacamentos(this string texto)
    {       
        string retorno = texto.Replace("\t", "").Replace(" ", "");
        return retorno.ToString();
    }

    public static string RemoverCaracteresEspeciais(this string texto) {
        string retorno = texto.RemoverAcentos();
        retorno = Regex.Replace(retorno.ToLower(), @"[^a-z0-9\s*]", "");
        return retorno;
    }

}
```

E usar da seguinte forma:

```
string entrada = "São Paulo SP";
string entradaNormalizada = entrada.RemoverCaracteresEspeciais()
                            .RemoverEspacamentos()
                            .ToLower();

string cadastro = "Cidade de São Paulo - SP";
string cadastroNormalizado = cadastro.RemoverCaracteresEspeciais()
                            .RemoverEspacamentos()
                            .ToLower();

bool comparacao = cadastroNormalizado.Contains(entradaNormalizada); // true
```

Ainda assim isso é só a primeira parte de sua jornada, pois mesmo após esses tratamentos básicos você só terá resultados positivos quando a entrada for menor que a base se comparação e estiverem na mesma ordem. Se a entrada for por exemplo "Eu moro na cidade de são paulo" ou "SP - São Paulo". A comparação será falsa.

Partindo desse ponto você deve enriquecer seu mecanismo para trabalhar com uma pontuação de acertos, comparando quantos termos A existem em B e tomar a sua decisão para validar a comparação.

Mas precisa de algo mais sofisticado vai precisar implementar uma API de busca que atenda as suas necessidades, como por exemplo o [Lucene](http://lucenenet.apache.org/) ou [RedDog.Search](https://github.com/reddog-io/RedDog.Search).

Comment: Leandro, obrigada mas infelizmente não conseguirei aplicar essa opção no projeto. Eu preciso de algo simples mesmo e é como voce disse, é apenas uma parte do que preciso fazer.